# Rocker sort of works, gives QXcpConnection errors

Tags: ros, docker, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use [rocker](https://github.com/osrf/rocker) with the [NVIDIA Container Toolkit](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) and I'm running into problems.

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
- nvidia-container-toolkit
- rocker 0.2.2

`docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-base nvidia-smi`
gives:

```
Fri Aug 28 17:07:36 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K1200        Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 51%   66C    P0     4W /  35W |   1636MiB /  4043MiB |      4%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`rocker --x11 --nvidia osrf/ros:eloquent-desktop rviz2` opens a window with rviz2 running and the main canvas visible in the center of the window. Yay! I can interact with the main canvas. But all of the controls (Qt, I guess) along the left, right and top are not drawn -- so most of the window is black. Meanwhile, I'm getting repeated errors like this in my docker container:

```
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 3726, resource id: 1200, major code: 130 (Unknown), minor code: 3
```

I'm a docker and rocker newbie. Any pointers?

Thanks.

Update: most problems go away when I use the `--user` option:

`rocker --x11 --nvidia --user osrf/ros:eloquent-desktop rviz2`

But when I run without a command (`rocker --x11 --nvidia --user osrf/ros:eloquent-desktop`) the problems eventually return. E.g., the first invocation of rviz2 works, but the 2nd results in the original behavior.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360531/rocker-sort-of-works,-gives-qxcpconnection-errors/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2020-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure why, but this worked for me: use `docker exec -it YOUR_CONTAINER_ID bash` to start a 2nd bash session in the container, and run `rqt` and `rviz2` from there.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2020-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0